# Building a linked list with two text files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
void ListaS::crearListaAleatoria(){
ifstream infile;
ifstream xfile;
infile.open("datosPrueba.txt");
xfile.open("datosPruebaNombres.txt");

int id;
char nombre[100];
int counter = 0;

//En caso de error
if (infile.fail()){
    cout << "Error opening file" <<endl;
    exit(1);
} if (xfile.fail()){
    cout << "Error opening file" <<endl;
    exit(1);
}

while(infile.eof() && xfile.eof()){
    Persona* p = new Persona();
    infile >> id;
    xfile >> nombre;
    p->setId(id);
    p->setNombre(nombre);
    agregar(p);


}
```

}

So I'm trying to build a linked list with two text files, one has numbers and the other has names, nonetheless, whenever I attempt to print the contents of this list, through another method I have somewhere else, it tells me I'm trying to access null values. The object `Persona*` is the place where I store the id and the name while `agregar()` is what creates the nodes to add to the list which is created elsewhere. Those things are not causing problems, its mainly those two values. I don't suppose there's some way to convert infile >> id to an int? Is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, the condition of your `while` loop is wrong (should be `while(!infile.eof() && !xfile.eof())`). But in C++ you usually do these things in a different way:

```
while(infile >> id && xfile >> nombre){
    Persona* p = new Persona();
    p->setId(id);
    p->setNombre(nombre);
    agregar(p);
}
```

This way you read the values from the files and check the `ifstream` state at the same time...and you avoid problems with last lines.

Comment: Wow, that worked phenomenally, thanks I thought no one was going to answer. No kidding about C++, everything gets done differently and I'm getting a little to used to Java for my own liking.